# how to work with foreign key in stored procedure in sql sever

Tags: sql, sql-server, stored-procedures

I have 2 tables arts and artist. I have written stored procedure for arts in which `artistId` is a foreign key. procedure for inserting data in table arts is as follows:

```
create procedure spInsertArts(
     @artsId int out,
     @name varchar(50),
     @category varchar(50),
     @artistId int
     )
     as
          begin
        select @artistId=SCOPE_IDENTITY()
            if exists(select artistId from artist)
              insert into arts(name,category,artistId) values(@name,@category,@artistId)
           end
```

When i execute it, it is giving error as:

> Procedure or function 'spInsertArts' expects parameter `@artistId', which was not supplied.

I want to set artistId to latest value of artistId in artist Table.

Answer (score 1):

If the artistId is always the latest value of artistId in the artist table, why do you need it as a parameter?

You can declare it as a local variable like this:

```
DECLARE @artistId INT
SET @artistId = ...
```

And get the latest artistId accordingly

Comment: artist is another table and artist is going to register and he will get id. And after that on second page he will insert arts info. i.e my arts table.I want that artistId to be inserted into arts table.

Answer (score 0):

If a parameter is optional, you need to provide a default value:

```
create procedure spInsertArts(
     @artsId int out,
     @name varchar(50),
     @category varchar(50),
     @artistId int = null
     )
```

But why is it even a parameter if you just override the value anyways?

Also I'm not sure determining the "latest" ID belongs here.  If the caller is inserting an artist, then turning around and inserting arts, then let the caller supply the `artistId`.  Otherwise the ONLY time you can insert arts is immediately after inserting an artist (and on the same connection).

Comment: its not optional, it always gets overwritten

Comment: actually it is like 'first artist is going to register and artistId will be there for every artist and when that artist gives art info i.e. in my arts table.the artistId should be inserted into arts table.'